# How to write to file when using Marshal::dump in Ruby for object serialization

Tags: ruby, serialization, marshalling, binary-serialization

Lets say I have the object **line** from class *Line*:

```
class Line
  def initialize point1, point2
    @p1 = point1
    @p2 = point2
  end
end
```

**line = Line.new...**

How can I binary serialize the line object? I tried with:

```
data = Marshal::dump(line, "path/to/still/unexisting/file")
```

but it created file and didn't add anything. I read the Class: IO documentation but I couldn't really get it.

Comment: Marshal isn't a good choice for persistent storage, the binary format depends on the specific Ruby version you're using. You're better off using a generic format like JSON, YAML, XML, ...

Comment: @muistooshort it's a great choice if you are comfortable with recreating it if the ruby version changes, and you have lots of data/vars that you need saved.  It's also pretty fast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
class Line
  attr_reader :p1, :p2
  def initialize point1, point2
    @p1 = point1
    @p2 = point2
  end
end

line = Line.new([1,2], [3,4])
```

Save `line`:

```
FNAME = 'my_file'

File.open(FNAME, 'wb') {|f| f.write(Marshal.dump(line))}
```

Retrieve into `line1`:

```
line1 = Marshal.load(File.binread(FNAME))
```

Confirm it works:

```
line1.p1 # => [1, 2]
```

Comment: Why `File.open(FNAME, 'wb') {|f| f.write(Marshal.dump(line))}` works well, but using `f = File.open(FNAME, 'wb')` and `f.write(Marshal.dump(line))` causes 'marshal data too short (ArgumentError)' when loading?

Comment: @KaRolthas, interesting question. The answer is that when `open` is used with a block the file is closed after the block is executed. When `open` does not have a block you need to close the file (`f.close`) after writing. If you don't close the file `File.binread(FNAME)` attempts to read an open file, causing the error.